# How to format the leading dots of section page number and subsection page number respectively in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

everyone:

I came across a problem. Following is how I format my table of contents:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\tocloftpagestyle{empty}

\renewcommand{\cftdot}{…}

\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{0}

\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

Its effect is as follows:
[image]

My question is How to format the leading dots of section page number and subsection page number respectively. I want a different leading line for my subsection page number.
I do not know how to set up it separately.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is what you are asking:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{7}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\bfseries\large\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecdotsep}{4}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecleader{\normalsize\cftdotfill{\cftsubsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand\cftsubsubsecleader{\small\cftdotfill{\cftsubsubsecdotsep}}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So how to align the different leading lines? They are ragged on the right.

Comment: @LawrenceLiu So it's do this for me.